# How to reduce height of a View in a List in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

Is it possible to reduce the height of a row in a SwiftUI List? I can't seem to get it to go smaller than the default height.

I tried adding `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` on `ForEach` but it just changes the trailing and leading padding.

In UIKit, I could just use the `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` to adjust the height to the desired size.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("\(i)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change environment property defaultMinListRowHeight like this:

```
        List {
            ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { i in
                Text("\(i)")
            }.frame(height: 2)
        }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: That didn't have any effect for me